# Getting error: "Error constructing proxy for org.gnome... Could not connect: Connection refused" when running gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, permissions, centos, dbus

I am getting the error: "Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Could not connect: Connection refused" when I try to run gnome-terminal. I am running CentOS 7. I am using SSH to remotely connect to the VM and am using VcXsrv to get the GUI.

When I try to run terminator, I get a similar error:
"Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-8LlMXZC0jW: Connection refused"

I think this is related to a permissions issue as gnome-terminal runs fine when I run it as sudo. It was also working fine some time ago so I believe I messed up some file permissions somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred to me when I connected to the same X Server from two different X clients simultaneously. Both were connected through SSH with forwarding and they used the same screen number. Closing one of the SSH connections fixed it.

The second error `Failed to connect to socket` is another issue. It does not prevent the terminal from running.